# Use OR Match in Sphinx to get longest match?

Tags: sphinx

Say I have two records in table:

- America
- United States of America

And I want to process a search for

```
United States of America
```

as

```
"America"|"United States of America"
```

I'll get both records. What I am trying to match is the longest string match, "United States of America". Is there a way to indicate this in search vs post-processing? I could of course store wordLength with both and do so but was hoping I could tell Sphinx to return the SINGLE match that is longest.

Comment: Use `index_field_lengths` to have sphinx automatically compute and store the 'wordLength' for you. If you dont store it somewhere, then sphinx can't use it. Putting it in an attribute allows you to sort by the field length, to get the longest first.

Comment: @BarryHunter I enableds that in the index however I can't use it in the order by command. Interestingly I also indexed my own mysql field "Name_Length" which I ran and stored with table. When I use order by Name_Length in the SphinxQL query that fails to sort correctly.